# Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY' for every INSERT query I am trying in a particular table

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, primary-key, sql-insert

I have the following table structure (using `SHOW CREATE` command just now):

```
CREATE TABLE `ipstats` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ip` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    `online` ENUM('n','y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'y',
    `last_used` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '1981-09-30 00:00:00',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `ip` (`ip`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=253691;
```

Now, I simply fetch a few recent values (I've changed the IPs for demonstration):

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM ipstats ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10;
+--------+----------------+--------+---------------------+
| id     | ip             | online | last_used           |
+--------+----------------+--------+---------------------+
| 253690 | 10.204.102.38  | n      | 2013-10-19 14:14:33 |
| 253689 | 10.188.124.196 | n      | 2013-10-19 10:46:25 |
| 253688 | 10.166.124.194 | n      | 2013-10-19 16:49:40 |
| 253687 | 10.250.137.166 | n      | 2013-10-19 13:51:56 |
| 253686 | 10.221.102.39  | n      | 2013-10-19 14:13:03 |
| 253685 | 10.129.102.57  | n      | 2013-10-19 18:45:20 |
| 253684 | 10.214.102.39  | n      | 2013-10-19 03:43:55 |
| 253683 | 10.31.142.41   | n      | 2013-10-19 17:27:08 |
| 253682 | 10.41.142.154  | n      | 2013-10-19 00:52:11 |
| 253681 | 10.41.124.84   | n      | 2013-10-19 10:37:12 |
+--------+----------------+--------+---------------------+
```

After this, I'll try to execute a simple `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO `ipstats` (`ip`, `last_used`)
VALUES ( '10.3.100.244', NOW() )
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `online` = 'y',
    `last_used` = NOW(),
    `id` = LAST_INSERT_ID(`id`)
```

where the value `10.3.100.244` does not already exist in the table. It results in:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '253691' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Selecting the `LAST_INSERT_ID` gives:

```
mysql> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
+------------------+
| LAST_INSERT_ID() |
+------------------+
|                0 |
+------------------+
```

If that wasn't already weird behaviour; I'll try to insert an already existing IP entry:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO `ipstats` (`ip`, `last_used`) VALUES ( '10.204.102.38', NOW() ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `online` = 'y', `last_used` = NOW(), `id` = LAST_INSERT_ID(`id`);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '253691' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I'm now officially stumped at this behaviour from MySQL. All other queries are working fine in all other processes that are running. The error is occurring only when I try to `INSERT` to the `ipstats` table. I even tried the following:

```
mysql> UPDATE ipstats
SET `online` = 'n',
    `last_used` = NOW(),
    `id` = LAST_INSERT_ID(`id`)
WHERE ip = '10.204.102.38';
Affected rows: 1  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.000 sec.
mysql> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
+------------------+
| LAST_INSERT_ID() |
+------------------+
|           253690 |
+------------------+
Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 1  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.000 sec.
mysql> INSERT INTO `ipstats` (`ip`, `last_used`)
VALUES ( '10.204.102.38', NOW() )
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `online` = 'y',
    `last_used` = NOW(),
    `id` = LAST_INSERT_ID(`id`);
Error 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '253691' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

What could be the problem? How can I resolve this? The error has been occurring since today afternoon and I never faced such a problem before.

**P.S.**: The error occurs with all user-accounts in my MySQL installation. There are 4 users (including root) who can access the database. None of them is able to perform the `INSERT` query.

Comment: +1 for the information given.

Comment: What is this supposed to achieve? `id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)`

Comment: Still i think you should remove the id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id) like i had in mine answer what i did removed..

Comment: @ypercube http://stackoverflow.com/q/16704586/1190388

Comment: @RaymondNijland I'm using the `LAST_INSERT_ID` to insert an entry in my other table(whose create table I mentioned once [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11171354/1190388))

Comment: What is the exact version of MySQL?

Comment: Are you sure this INSERT produces the error and not the next (if it's in a script)?

Comment: @ypercube I thought so too at first. The above outputs shown are from terminal (opened using `mysql -p` with user `root`).

Comment: @hjpotter92 on sqlfiddle i did see 1 or 2 times the same error as you but i dont get it anymore maybe  you should make an sqldump off your table, drop the table and just rebuild the table again or rebuild by ALTER TABLE ipstats ENGINE = MyISAM;

Comment: @hjpotter92 Or just stop using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE it's just an non portable extension on the ANSI SQL INSERT specification..

Answer (score 1):

A force insertion of a new row (with `id` different from `253691`) seems to have solved this problem for now. I am still not sure as to why the error occurred.

The command I used was:

```
INSERT INTO `ipstats` (id, ip, online, last_used)
VALUES ( 253699, '10.204.102.38', 'n', NOW() );
```

and the system was working normally again (for all 4 users, on every connection). I'll leave the question as still unanswered since I still don't know what caused the problem. My best guess would be that it is a possible MySQL bug.

Comment: You should [`check`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisamchk.html) the table. Perhaps the table or an index was corrupted.